# Call logos objective-c category from preferences bundle - jailbroken ios development

Tags: ios, categories, jailbreak, theos, logos

Lets say I define a function as a category of UIDevice in Tweak.xm using Logos:

```
%hook UIDevice
%new(v@:)
+(void)setWallpaperImageFromImagePath:(NSString *)wallpaperImagePath option:(int)option{
    //Do something
}//end method
%end
```

Then say that I have a preferences bundle and need to call this logos function from the .m file of the preferences project. Is this possible? So far I have not found a working way of doing this.

Also, I have this in the preferences .m file:

```
@interface UIDevice (flowAddons)
+(void)setWallpaperImageFromImagePath:(NSString *)wallpaperImagePath option:(int)option;
@end
```

This compiles fine, but when I run it, and I call this this function from the .m preferences file, it crashes.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can add method to a class and call it. I do it myself in my tweaks. Also, I use objc runtime API to do that but it doesn't matter. As for crashes, I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. What you must understand is that your tweak is just a dynamic library that's being loaded in address space of a specific process. It means that you're limited by that address space. You can add methods to classes in your tweak that you can later call. Those methods will be visible to everyone in that address space but not outside of it.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample or link to one of your projects?

Comment: `class_addMethod([self class], @selector(BackgroundWorker), (IMP)BackgroundWorker_imp, "v@:");`, that's it. And I just spotted one problem in your code - `%new(v@:)` is wrong type encoding for your method. It should be `%new(v@:@i)`.